# Excel Add-Ins Sometimes Do Not Load

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few excel add-ins that fail to load sometimes when I open an existing workbook. Here are some of the pertinent facts and things I have noticed when trying to diagnose:

- These are regular excel add-ins, not COM add-ins.
- Add-ins always load when opening excel from the program menu.
- Add-ins do not load ~10-20% of the time when opening a workbook from email/shared drive/personal drive.
- I am unable to consistently replicate the issue.  Sometimes the opening the same workbook will load the add-ins, sometime it won't.
- The issue might be connected to one of the toolkits that has an installer built into it.  (the idea behind this add-in is that it can be sent to people, and they can install it just by opening.  Then, once it's installed in the AddIns folder, it no longer does anything when the add-in is loaded).

  ```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  If Right(ThisWorkbook.Path, 6) <> "AddIns" Then

   Dim blRegister As Boolean
   Dim ThisAddIn As AddIn

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   On Error Resume Next

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installing").Activate

   Application.AddIns("Toolkit").Installed = False

   ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "Z:\AppData\Microsoft\AddIns\ToolKit.xlam", AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, FileFormat:=55

   On Error GoTo 0

   blRegister = Application.RegisterXLL("Z:\AppData\Microsoft\AddIns\ToolKit.xlam")

   Set ThisAddIn = Application.AddIns.Add("Z:\AppData\Microsoft\AddIns\ToolKit.xlam")
   ThisAddIn.Installed = True

   MsgBox "Thanks for Installing the Toolkit!"
   ThisWorkbook.Close False

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  End If

  End Sub
  ```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you are assuming "Z:\" always present and accessible on all the computers? Normally AddIns are stored in partition with Operating System (C:\).

Comment: Correct, in this case Z: is accessible on all computers (equivalent of C: drive)

Comment: May be you need to do more before the SaveAs. You may need to Close the addin workbook that the `AddIns("Toolkit").Name` refers to when `AddIns("Toolkit").IsOpen = True`, then `Application.EnableEvents = False`, open the addin after `ThisAddIn.Installed = True` and then `Application.EnableEvents = True` before `ThisWorkbook.Close`. The thing is, unless `Debug.Print` is used on every step, you can't tell where it fails.

Comment: To tell where it fails add line number and include erl in your output.  And run the sub via an ontimer in a Module.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem.  JKP says maybe cause by download from internet flag.  Not my problem though.
http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel-Add-ins-fail-to-load.asp